# Is it possible to have a background image not display in a certain element?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a background image *not* display in a certain element?-

Example -
If I have 3 divs inside of div that has a background image all inside a `<body>` tag that has a background image. Is there some way to show the `<body>` background image (BodyBackground.jpg) instead of the `<div>` background image (DivBackground.jpg) in the center div?

```
<body style="background-image:url('/Content/Images/BodyBackground.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-y;">
   <div style="background-image:url('/Content/Images/DivBackground.jpg')">
      <div style="height:100px;width:200px"></div>
      <div style="height:100px;width:200px"> SHOW BodyBackground.jpg IMAGE HERE </div>
      <div style="height:100px;width:200px"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you set a background colour to the middle `div` to overlay the parent?

Comment: No. I can't. Thanks, setek. I actually will have two background images. One for the whole body, one for the large div.

Comment: Does <div style="height:100px;width:200px;background-color:white;">...</div> help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **make** it look like it using `fixed` position.

HTML:

```
<body style="background:url('/Content/Images/BodyBackground.jpg') repeat-y;">
    <div style="background-image:url('/Content/Images/DivBackground.jpg')">
        <div style="height:100px;width:200px"></div>
        <div style="height:100px;width:200px;background:url('/Content/Images/BodyBackground.jpg') fixed;"> 
            SHOW BodyBackground.jpg IMAGE HERE
        </div>
        <div style="height:100px;width:200px"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Because the background position is set to `fixed` its position is global to the whole page and not the div itself. Even if you change the position of the elements in the page it'll still **look like** that area is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <body style="background-image:url('/Content/Images/BodyBackground.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-y;">
   <div style="background-image:url('/Content/Images/DivBackground.jpg')">
      <div style="height:100px;width:200px"></div>
      <div style="height:100px;width:200px;background-image:url('/Content/Images/BodyBackground.jpg')!important;"> SHOW BodyBackground.jpg IMAGE HERE </div>
      <div style="height:100px;width:200px"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, Miss Chetan Gawai. I further clarified my question. I think your answer would work with the way I originally asked the question, but I don't it will solve the issue the way I have now asked it.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that the pattern of the background image will probably not line up.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a CSS class that defines the background image. And then use the CSS class accordingly?

Eg.

```
.body-bg{
    Background-image:url(...);
}
.div-bg{
    Background-image:url(...);
}
body class="body-bg"> 
    div class="div-bg></div>
    div class="body-bg></div>
    div class="div-bg></div>
/body>
```

Comment: Hey Yunus, The problem with that solution is that the pattern of the background image will probably not line up.